# Can't install plugin in eclipse due to dependency on bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.8.0

Tags: android, plugins, emulation, genymotion

I am getting continuous failed installation problems while installing the **Genymotion plugin** for eclipse.

The error log says "*It requires the bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.8.0*".

**Error Log:**

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Genymotion Eclipse Tools 1.0.1.201307161043 (com.genymobile.genymotion.ide.eclipse.feature.group 1.0.1.201307161043)
  Missing requirement: Genymotion 1.0.1.201307161043 (com.genymobile.genymotion.ide.eclipse.plugin 1.0.1.201307161043) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.8.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Genymotion Eclipse Tools 1.0.1.201307161043 (com.genymobile.genymotion.ide.eclipse.feature.group 1.0.1.201307161043)
    To: com.genymobile.genymotion.ide.eclipse.plugin [1.0.1.201307161043]
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if you do have it?

Comment: I don't know how to check the list of installed dependencies. Also, if it is not there, how to install it ?

Comment: In eclipse go to Help -> 'Install New Software...' then select 'What is already installed'. Select the Plug-ins tab and click the Providers header to sort by provider name. Scroll down to Eclipse.org and look in the 'Plug-in Name' column for 'Core Runtime' and then check the Version column. I have 3.8.0.v20120912-155025 installed. If it isn't installed or isn't 3.8.0 all I'd suggest is going back to 'Install New Software..' and doing a check to see if there are any updates available for your environment.

Comment: I an having 3.6.0. Thanks, I am checking for updates and I will update it once I find its update.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this? I am getting the same error and it's driving me nuts! Why does this have to be so bloody difficult?!

Comment: Did you solve this?? I have the same problem, but there is no update available yet it seems.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is simply installing Eclipse Juno (or higher) and installing Genymotion plugin in that instance.

It seems Eclipse Indigo doesn't include an updated version of `org.eclipse.core.runtime`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply modifying the name that I had entered for the plugin that I was installing. In the name text field option available after clicking add new on help > Install new software, make sure the name you provide is one word(could include underscores) without any spaces in it.

Comment: my eclipse version is helios 3.6

Answer (score -1):

If Help->check for updates doesn't help, download an updated Eclipse version from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/